# material ui dropdown validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, javascript-objects

I am trying to validate my dropdown field wherein if the value is empty the box should have a red border and text in red color should become visible to say that the box cannot be left blank. I am using normal javascript for the validation even though it may not be ideal but please give me a solution in this format only. I am using document.getElementById to get the id of the input html. However I am not able to validate the dropdown box.

Here is my code:

```html
<Grid item xs={6}>
  <FormControl
    id="UOM_Before"
    style={{ width: "80%" }}
    size="small"
  >
    <InputLabel
      htmlFor="UOM_Before"
      id="UOM_Before"
      style={{
        marginLeft: 10,
        top: "50%",
        transform: "translate(0,-50%"
      }}
    >
      UOM
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="UOM_Before"
      id="UOM_Before"
      name="UOM_Before"
      onChange={handleChange("UOM_Before")}
      defaultValue={values.UOM_Before}
      variant="outlined"
      inputProps={{
        id: "UOM_Before",
        name: "age"
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem value="Nos">Nos</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="Percentage">Percentage</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="Metric">Metric</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
  <label
    id="uom_before"
    style={{ visibility: "hidden", color: "red" }}
  >
    UOM cannot be left blank
  </label>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code for the validation:

```js
handleAddRow = () => {

  if (document.getElementById("UOM_Before").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("uom_before").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("UOM_Before").style.border = "1px solid red";
  } else {
    const item = {
      Kpi_Before: [],
      UOM_Before: "",
      Base_Before: "",
      Target_Before: "",
      dateTime: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  }
  
};
```

Comment: You have the same `id` (`UOM_Before`) on at least 4 different elements (FormControl, InputLabel, Select, and the input within the Select). You should give them all distinct ids.

Comment: Yes changed the ids and it worked